# Grep part of a file name and output to a .txt

Tags: bash, grep, find

I'm trying to grep pattern (the first 8 characters) for all files names in a directory and output to a .txt using this but it's not working.
Why is that?

```
find . -type f -print | grep "^........" > test.txt
```

it still outputs the whole file name to the .txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use to grep at all, you can use the [`cut`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cut) command to get the first `1-N` characters without pattern matching:

```
find . -type f -print | cut -c1-8 > test.txt
```

Comment: Awesome! Do you know what is wrong with the grep thing though?

Comment: I don't have a terminal to test it on right now, but I think you might need the `-E` flag to enable the extended regex mode of grep.

Comment: You also might need the `-o` flag to cut out everything else that doesn't match, so I think it would be something like this: `grep -Eo "^........"` or `grep -Eo "^.{8}"` (with the repetition operator)

Comment: Coo. Do you know how do I do find, so that doesnt include files in subdirectories? :)

Comment: I think you need to set `-maxdepth` to `0` or `1`, but I forget which one only means the top level. All of the options that `find` accepts can be found in the manual page: https://linux.die.net/man/1/find

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the output of the find command to grep, rather than passing the output as a list of files for grep to search. You can fix it with xargs like this:

```
find . -type f -print | xargs grep "^........" > test.txt
```

Comment: I don't think this is what they were asking for. They wanted the first 8 characters of the filename, not the contents of the file.